# In which episode of "My Hero Academia" did Bakugo yell at a little girl...?

Tags: episode-identification, my-hero-academia

I found this clip, but the description doesn't credit where it's from. Does anyone know where it's from, and where I can watch the full episode?

Answer (score 9):

This isn't from an episode of the regular series; it's from the feature film *[My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Hero_Academia:_Heroes_Rising)*. The film is set after the Meta Liberation Army arc, which the anime hasn't reached yet (I believe it will form the second half of Season 5, which is currently airing).

*Heroes Rising* is currently available on Blu-Ray. I'm unaware of any legal streaming sites that have the film, and Stack Exchange does not endorse piracy, so I cannot and will not link you to any illegal streaming/torrent sites.